# run JUnit 4 Groovy tests in order

Tags: selenium, jenkins, groovy, junit4, geb

Currently I'm creating some Gebish tests. For easier understanding for myself I'm using the Class name as a case and the method as a step.

Because of my idea I need a specific order to pass all tests. For that I put a-z in front of the files and class names.
With `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` I found a way to run the methods in an order. Now I'm stuck to run the classes in a specific order and I don't know how to fix it.

When I'm running it in Intellij, it has no order.
When I'm running it through the command line through gradle, it's running from a-z.
When I'm running it through Jenkins, it has no order too.

Now, how can I run the tests classes in an alphabetical order?

Comment: Why do you need them to run in a particular order?

Comment: I'm trying to test a whole shop. For that I have e.g. registration and profile functions. The profile functions (including deleting the account) are needing an account. That account is creating through the registration. It would be not smart to start with e.g. change password and then delete the account.

Comment: Ok - it's very bad practice to have tests that depend on other tests.  You should aim to write each test to be completely independent of everything else.

Comment: I know that, but it wouldn't be smart to create for some test cases a new account each time. To save a lot of time with the tests and because of the buch of accounts I'm looking for a nice workaround.

Comment: You can move things to `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` methods, or use mocks to avoid the runtime cost.

Comment: Check this: https://blogs.oracle.com/mindless/entry/controlling_the_order_of_junit

Comment: Start with an already existing set of test data. Have a test database that contains: one account that you can use for your profile functions, one account for testing the account deletion, perform a registration for a random username/pass and test that it was created successfully. At the end of your test, drop the test data set and recreate it before running the tests again. You can have a script doing this automatically for you. This way, you can keep your tests separate and independent.